# Sandboxing a .NET Assembly - Upload a DLL and then Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, system.reflection

I'd like to write an MVC application that allows someone in our development group to upload a .NET assembly, and then I want to reflect over the .dll to gather information from it. I want to do this safely. Never loaded an assembly like this in a "sandbox". What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is inspect metadata than you can use [`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx). Loading an assembly with this API loads the assembly, but none of the code inside of it is executable:

> You cannot execute code from an assembly that has been loaded into the reflection-only context. To execute the code, load the assembly with the LoadFile method.

You may want to do this in a new AppDomain if you need to be able to unload the assembly. Assemblies cannot be unloaded, but AppDomains containing them can.

If you need to execute some code, but want to ensure the library doesn't do anything bad, you can load a new AppDomain and use code permissions to restrict the AppDomain. [This CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120911/CAS-Code-access-security-NET-4-0-Security-model-FA) gives a nice walk-through on how to do it.